# Output percentage and game number from arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a Rock, Paper, Scissor game for a school assignment using arrays. I am trying to output the Game number on screen as games are played but my counter is not working (this area is the trouble). Also I need to show the % of games that are draws but it stays at 0. I appreciate any feedback as I am only 2 months into JavaScript and also Stackoverflow. Thanks everyone.

```
//Read through PlayerArray for games won by player
            function PlayerStatistics(){
                //Player Statistics
                var PlayerWin = 0;

                //Draw Statistics
                var DrawCount = 0;
                var RockCount = 0;
                var PaperCount = 0;
                var ScissorCount = 0;

                for(var index = 0; index < PlayerArray.length; index++) {
                    if (PlayerArray[index] == "Draw"){
                        DrawCount++;
                    }

                    if (PlayerArray[index] == "Rock"){
                        RockCount++;
                    }
                    if (PlayerArray[index] == "Paper"){
                        PaperCount++;
                    }
                    if (PlayerArray[index] == "Scissor"){
                        ScissorCount++;
                    }

                    //Count each win only from Player
                    if (ResultArray[index] == "Player"){
                        PlayerWin++;
                    }
                    //Count number of games
                    var GameCount = PlayerArray.length;
                    var DrawCount = PlayerArray.length;


                var PlayerWinPercentage = PlayerWin/ResultArray.length * 100;
                var DrawPercentage = DrawCount/ResultArray.length * 100;

            <td id="RockBackground"><img id="PlayerRock" src="Rock.jpg" ></td>
            <td id="PaperBackground"><img id="PlayerPaper" src="Paper.jpg"></td>
            <td id="ScissorBackground"><img id="PlayerScissor"   src="Scissors.jpg"></td>
            <td id="GameCount">Game Number</td>
            <td id="RockComputerBackground"><img id="ComputerRock" src="Rock.jpg"></td>
            <td id="PaperComputerBackground"><img id="ComputerPaper" src="Paper.jpg"></td>
            <td id="ScissorComputerBackground"><img id="ComputerScissor" src="Scissors.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="result" colspan="7">Winner</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id=""><button id="First5">First 5 Games</td>
            <td id=""><button id="Last5">Last 5 Games</td>
            <td id=""><button id="PlayerStatistics">Player Statistics</td>
            <td id=""><button id="PlayerWon">Games Player has won</td>
            <td id=""><button id="Results">Results of all games in a session</td>
            <td id=""><button id="NewSession">New Session</button></td>
            <td id=""><button id="accButton">Standard Mode</button></td>
        </tr>`enter code here`
        <tr>
            <td id="OutputResults" colspan="7">Results</td>
```

Comment: Can you post sample data that you're testing with?

Answer (score 0):

This code right here:

```
//Count number of games
var GameCount = PlayerArray.length;
var DrawCount = PlayerArray.length;
```

You throw the DrawCount out and reset the count to be the length of the PlayerArray.

Also, I'm not entirely clear on how you guarantee that PlayerArray and ResultArray will be the same length and have the right things at the same index, but that's probably outside the scope of this question.

Comment: With player and CPU choices im pushing the choice into their arrays and every selection the player makes ie how many times each rock, paper and scissor is selected, which works. Each selection i increment the arrays:

for(var index = 0; index < PlayerArray.length; index++) {
if (PlayerArray[index] == "Draw"){
  DrawCount++;
}
     
if (PlayerArray[index] == "Rock"){
 RockCount++;
}
if (PlayerArray[index] == "Paper"){
 PaperCount++;
}
if (PlayerArray[index] == "Scissor"){
 ScissorCount++;
}

Comment: Ok, first please don't put code in comments it's super hard to read, especially since you already have that code in your post.  Second, I see that, though the code you've posted seems incomplete (e.g. lack of matching }'s).  Third, from what you did post it looks like you're *resetting* the DrawCount variable to the length of the PlayerArray on every iteration of the loop, as i said in my answer.

Comment: Apologies for the format, I changed the PlayerArray.index == Draw to my results array and it now works as I wanted so now that I figured that out i just need to output the game number as each game is played. You cant see it in this code because i didnt include it but all braces are fine. I have event listeners for my selections. Each selection stores into their appropriate arrays which is all working. I just need to make a counter for the game numbers. Can you assist with this?

Comment: Sorry it's not at all clear what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok ill try simplify what im looking for. In my code I have a table, refer to this part of the table <td id="GameCount">Game Number</td>. In this cell i need to show every game that occurs. So once the player clicks a selection the "Game Number" Needs to show 1 and so on as games continue. I cannot work out how to show the game numbers increment in the cell. Does that make sense?